# Assets and XHR (Ajax) requests over https

Tags: ajax, assets

I have our main site on a development server which does not have https enabled. Yet I'm noticing the following errors:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://staging.ginghamsburg.org/?ACT=28. Origin http://staging.ginghamsburg.org is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

My config file handles ssl via the following options:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) {
$config['site_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
} else {
$config['site_url'] = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
}
```

What seems to be happening as a result is that none of the folder contents or subfolders display in the Assets window.

Comment: Do you have $config['assets_site_url'] set in your config file? If so that takes precedence over the Site URL.

Comment: Interesting...I added

    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) {
        $config['assets_site_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
    } else {
        $config['assets_site_url'] = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
    }

and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting...I added

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) {
    $config['assets_site_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
} else {
    $config['assets_site_url'] = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
}
```

and it worked. I wonder why the override was needed?

Thanks Brandon!

Comment: Weird. Assets just calls `$EE->functions->fetch_site_index()` in the event that $config['assets_site_url'] isn’t set, and that function will check `$config['site_url']`, so I’m not sure why the https:// wasn’t getting picked up.

Comment: If you’re going to the trouble of adding `$config['assets_site_url']`, you might as well add “index.php” to the end of that, so there’s less of a chance that the request will hit your .htaccess redirect.